# Probability of decision on arrival of "new" information

Tags: probability, statistics

I just decided to share a new problem (Rice's book, problem 1.58) and supposed solution:

A teacher tells three boys, Drew, Chris and Jason, that two of them will have to stay after school to help clean erasers and that one of them will be able to leave. She further says that she has made a decision as to who will leave and whol will stay at random by rolling three-sided die. Drew wants to leave to play soccer and has a clever idea about how to increase his chances of doing so.

**He figures that ONE OF Jason and Chris will CERTAINLY stay and asks the teacher to tell the name of one of the two who will stay.**

Drew's idea is that if, for example, Jason is named, then he and Chris are left and they each have probability $\frac{1}{2}$ of leaving; similarly, if Chris is named, Drew's probability of leaving is still $\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, by merely asking the teacher a question, Drew will increase his probability of leaving from $\frac{1}{3}$  to $\frac{1}{2}$. What do you think of this scheme?

My idea is that: There's in fact no information if he learns who among Jason or Chris will stay, because one of them wll defenitely stay.

1. It is obvoius that before asking his teacher a question the probability that Drew leaves is $\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}({\rm leaves} | {\rm before\ asking\ question})=\frac{1}{3}$.
2. After asking his teacher a question: 
   $\mathbb{P}({\rm leaves} | {\rm who\ will\ stay\ among\ Chris\ and\ Jason})=
   \mathbb{P}({\rm leaves} | {\rm who\ will\ stay\ among\ Chris\ and\ Jason|teacher\ says\ Chris\ stays})\times\mathbb{P}({\rm teacher\ says\ Chris\ stays}) + \mathbb{P}({\rm leaves} | {\rm who\ will\ stay\ among\ Chris\ and\ Jason|teacher\ says\ Jason\ stays})\times\mathbb{P}({\rm teacher\ says\ Jason\ stays})=p_1\times \mathbb{P}({\rm teacher\ says\ Chris\ stays}) +p_2\times \mathbb{P}({\rm teacher\ says\ Jason\ stays})$.

It can be easily seen, that if either Jason or Chris stay, the probability that Drew leaves is $\frac{1}{2}$, therefore $p_1=p_2=\frac{1}{2}$. Also the probability that either Jason or Chris stay is $\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore the expression above equals $\frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}$.

In conclusion, asking teacher his question gives him no advantage at all.

Comment: While your final conclusion is correct, I think your paragraph 2 and the next paragraph are confused between for example "Chris stays" and "teacher says Chris stays".

Comment: Interesting to contrast with the Monty Hall Problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Comment: Henry, yes thanks. I just didn't express it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wrote in the end is confused. You say: "It can be easily seen that if either Jason or Chris stay, the probability that Drew leaves is $1/2$". This is true if the teacher decides to tell Drew one person who stays, picking him randomly from the set {Jason, Chris, Drew}, and it happens to be for example Chris (same for Jason). This has a $1/3$ probability of happening, as you sayd: "Also the probability that either Jason or Chris stay is $1/3$", writing it not much precisely because the effective probability that for example Chris stays knowing nothing else is $2/3$. Then your calculation is correct, but it leads to an answer that you already knew, the fact that Drew has a $1/3$ probability to leave before the theacher says anything. So I think what you did in paraghraph 2. is the same as in paragraph 1., that is the calculation before having the teacher's information. 
Your problem is a version of Monty Hall problem without the possibility of changing door, but the results are the same. Informally you can resolve the paradox realizing that before the theacher speaks, the chances that one between Jason and Chris will leave are $2/3$, so if the teacher tells Drew that Chris will stay, then these $2/3$ chances will "collapse" and must be attributed to the unique possibility left, Jason.
A clarifying variant of the problem can be obtained considering 100 students. As before only 1 can leave, and the teacher reveals Drew 98 persons who won't leave. Then it looks more obvious that the probability that Drew will leave cannot be $1/2$.